# How to add classes in my unit test, referencing doesn't give access

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

I'm a newbie trying to work out a small issue in Visual Studio 2019...

When i create a new project for unit testing in Visual Studio, I'm right clicking reference in solution manager and selecting my main project in the reference manager, which then populates my references with the correct project.
However i don't have access to the main projects classes, I can't call any of the methods etc.

I have checked my access specifiers are all public... 
I have tried adding using projectName; just to see...

I am following a old course so maybe somethings changed but I've gone over the content quite a few times and I'm stumped...

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Can't really tell from that description... Make sure you didn't mess .NET Framework and Core up, I am not sure how VS presents that when wrong. The classes and methods need to be public in the " i don't have access to the main projects classes", not just your test classes. If `internal` (the default for classes if not specified), there is an attribute that can be added to the assembly.

Comment: Yes so i did check that both are not core and are both on Framework. In the unit test i don't have access to methods or classes from the project I'm trying to reference. Everything in the project I'm trying to test is public...!

Comment: did you add the using declarations to for the namesapces used for the main project classes in your test file?

Comment: yes sir,  i tried that as well...

Comment: another clue to this is if i close the project and reopen the unit tests references are all yellow triangle error exclamation marked, even the references automatically generated...

Comment: Can you create a new project (e.g. "Class Library (.NET Framework)") give it some simple `public int Foo(int a, int b) { return a + b; }`, create a new unit test project, and reference that? If so see if you can compare the projects for any difference that you missed.